# Return response after async await function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am develop a small app, I have a problem. After I await to run query from Mongodb then I use map method to do some task then I return my response, but the response always return promise and I have not necessary data. Here my code

```
    exports.getListChallenges = async function (req, res) {
    var status_code = Consts.STATUS_CODE.ERROR.UNKOWN_ERROR;
    try {
        var page_number = parseInt(req.params.page_number);
        var page_size = parseInt(req.params.page_size);
        var challenges = await Challenge.find()
            .skip(page_size * (page_number - 1))
            .limit(page_size);            
        status_code = Consts.STATUS_CODE.SUCCESS.DATA_FOUND;

        challenges = challenges.map(async function (o) {
            var challenger_club = await Club.findById(o.challenger_club_id);
            var challege = {
                challenge: o,
                challenger_club_name: challenger_club.club_name,
                challenger_club_avatar: challenger_club.avatar
            };
            return challege;
        });

        res.json({
            "status": true,
            "message": "Challenges found !",
            "status_code": status_code,
            "challenges": challenges
        });

    } catch (error) {
        status_code = Consts.STATUS_CODE.ERROR.UNKOWN_ERROR;
        res.json({
            "status": false,
            "status_code": status_code,
            "error": error
        })
    }
}
```

the "challenges" in response always empty , how can I solve it ? thank !

Comment: `challenges = await Promise.all( challenges.map( async ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close - you've mapped each item in the initial `challenges` to a `Promise` that resolves to the `challenge` object you want, now you need to call `Promise.all` on that array of `Promises` to get the values they resolve to. To keep the code clear, it would be best not to reassign `challenges` unless it's necessary - call the new array of Promises something else, like `challengePromises`:

```
exports.getListChallenges = async function(req, res) {
  var status_code = Consts.STATUS_CODE.ERROR.UNKOWN_ERROR;
  try {
    var page_number = parseInt(req.params.page_number);
    var page_size = parseInt(req.params.page_size);
    var challenges = await Challenge.find()
      .skip(page_size * (page_number - 1))
      .limit(page_size);
    status_code = Consts.STATUS_CODE.SUCCESS.DATA_FOUND;

    var challengePromises = challenges.map(async function(o) {
      var challenger_club = await Club.findById(o.challenger_club_id);
      var challege = {
        challenge: o,
        challenger_club_name: challenger_club.club_name,
        challenger_club_avatar: challenger_club.avatar
      };
      return challege;
    });
    var challengeObjs = await Promise.all(challengePromises);

    res.json({
      "status": true,
      "message": "Challenges found !",
      "status_code": status_code,
      "challenges": challengeObjs
    });

  } catch (error) {
    status_code = Consts.STATUS_CODE.ERROR.UNKOWN_ERROR;
    res.json({
      "status": false,
      "status_code": status_code,
      "error": error
    })
  }
}
```

Also, just a suggestion, but if you're using `async` and `await`, you might consider going all the way with ES6+ syntax, such as `const` instead of `var`, arrow functions when possible, shorthand object properties, among other things - they can make code more concise and readable. For example, I'd refactor your code to:

```
exports.getListChallenges = async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const page_number = parseInt(req.params.page_number);
    const page_size = parseInt(req.params.page_size);
    const challengeData = await Challenge.find()
      .skip(page_size * (page_number - 1))
      .limit(page_size);
    const status_code = Consts.STATUS_CODE.SUCCESS.DATA_FOUND;
    const challengePromises = challengeData.map(async (o) => {
      const {
        club_name: challenger_club_name,
        avatar: challenger_club_avatar
      } = await Club.findById(o.challenger_club_id);
      return {
        challenge: o,
        challenger_club_name,
        challenger_club_avatar
      };
    });
    const challenges = await Promise.all(challengePromises);
    res.json({
      status: true,
      message: "Challenges found !",
      status_code,
      challenges
    });
  } catch (error) {
    const status_code = Consts.STATUS_CODE.ERROR.UNKOWN_ERROR;
    res.json({ status: false, status_code, error })
  }
}
```

Note that the `status_code` will always be `Consts.STATUS_CODE.ERROR.UNKOWN_ERROR` when there's an error, given the logic on your original code - there's no need to reassign it.

Comment: Yeah, it worked, thank you so much, your answer really details and make me more understand about asyn/await/promise .